# how to get only match column values in pandas between two same csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have two CSV file both have more than 50000 rows and now I want to find only matches records between two CSV files.
I have tried so many pandas function like and all records return response is only `true` and `false`.

How do I get only matches column values between two CSVs?

```
 df2 = id externalcode
       1   00
       2   00




 df2 = id externalcode
        1   00
        2   00
```

Any help would be appreciated. The code which I have tried is given below:

```
data_frame1 = pd.read_csv("one.csv")
data_frame2 = pd.read_csv("two.csv")
print(type(data_frame1),type(data_frame2))
result = data_frame1[data_frame1['id'] == data_frame2['id']]
df1 = data_frame1['id'].isin(data_frame2['id'])
df2 = data_frame1['values_externalCode'].isin(data_frame2['values_externalCode'])
```

Comment: You want matching rows or matching columns? Can you also add your desired output df? :

Comment: only want to match only column values between two data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = data_frame1[data_frame1['id'].isin(list(data_frame2['id']))]
```

I modified one of your attempts, please let me know if it works!
So this code will select ids in data_frame1 which also appear in data_frame2.